# Java Apache poi 4.1.2 comparing cell type

Tags: java, apache-poi

I tried to find similar questions on stack, but unfortunately none of them fully helps me.
Before new release, I have following code:

```
 if (c1.getCellType() == CellType.STRING) { //do sth }
```

After update I can not use it, because

> CellType.STRING

is no longer supported. How should I fix it?

I found solution:

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
  case STRING:
    //Do something
    break;
}
```

But I have no idea what is STRING? From which 'import' should it be?

Comment: What let you think enum `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType` is not part of `apache poi 4.1.2`? It actually is and it has `public static final CellType STRING` too.

Comment: Double check your Apache POI version and ensure you don't have any old jar files on your classpath, the code you're using ought to be fine with the latest version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had wrong import, thank guys.
Proper import:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
```